# Update Phonegap android application from version 2.7.0 to 3.3.0

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am looking to update my phonegap application from phonegap 2.7.0 to 3.3.0, not too sure how I go about doing this, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

personally I start by creating a new 3.3.0 project and moving my www from the old to new. Then build the project and see what does and doesn't work.

From there I would need to know more about specific functionality you are looking to update.

The biggest thing to note is that everything is a plugin in 3.x So if you use alert notifications, device id, check network connection, anything like that, you will need to first install those features as plugins. The pg docs have been updated to show which plugin relates which feature.

Comment: The only reason I am trying to do this is because I want to implement some plugins in my current application, am I wasting my time updating? could I install these plugins with phonegap 2.7.0 anyway?

Comment: it depends on the plugins. Not all plugins have been updated for 3.x and I have been spending a good amount updating plugins I need. You may want to check which version the plugins built for currently and go with the version that will require the least amount of work.